# Lenguaje bajo python

Tags: python

Quería consultar si alguno sabe si el intérprete de python está programado directamente en assembly o realizado en C por ejemplo o en qué?. Es una duda de la que no pude encontrar respuesta en Google.

Comment: No termino de ver qué puede aportar esta información. La respuesta la puedes encontrar descargando el código fuente. Si viendo el código fuente no eres capaz de identificar el lenguaje del cual se trata tienes ante ti una demostración de que antes de meterte en estos berenjenales tienes que mejorar tus conocimientos relacionados con la programación. Por cierto, te recomiendo visitar el [tour] para que aprendas cómo funciona este sitio.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un problema de programación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de mirar el código fuente de python y aparentemente en su gran mayoria esta hecho en C.

Saludos,

[Código fuente](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/)

Comment: Gracias eferion y David. No supe donde encontrar el código fuente. No sabía más que en Github. Saludos